# Multicast with same IP generated by different servers

Tags: windows, networking, multicast

I have a simple config where 2 Windows servers are generating each multicasts on the same addresses.

For example, on a direct Ethernet wired link between the servers they both generate the multicast 239.193.17.17:6895.

On another NIC, where there is a simple network switch in between the servers,  they both generate the multicast 239.193.18.18:6888.

Is there a conflict caused by using the same multicast IPs in this configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In fact, multiple sources sending traffic to the same multicast group is completely normal, for example in service discovery protocols like [SSDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol).

They’re still regular IP packets with a sender address, making the various sources identifiable.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. These multicasts are digital video broadcasting (DVB) transport streams and I want to analyze them with a DVB analyzer. I suppose it depends on the DVB analyzer if it can handle this, correct? But normally, I suppose it should.

Comment: Yes. If you want to improve your chances, you could perhaps use different destination ports.